# TinyMCE setcontent in Joomla wont set the content in tinymce after jQuery(document).ready(function()

Tags: joomla, tinymce, joomla2.5

When I do at the bottom of a view and after some html:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("asdsad");
    });
```

I get an Error in firefox

> Error: TypeError: tinyMCE.activeEditor is null

When I add the line in a function and activate it after a click event, the code works, for example

```
<input type="button" onclick="setcontent()" value="Set the content" >

<script>
    function setcontent(){
      tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("asdsad");
    }
</script>
```

I am thinking that TinyMCE has not finished loading after jQuery(document).ready ? or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a handler for inserting text for every editor plugin in Joomla

Try `jInsertEditorText('hello world', 'jform_articletext');`

where second argument is the id of JForm editor field (for com_content it's `jform_articletext`). This way you are able to insert content to whatever editor is currently used (tinyMCE, codemirror ...).

Comment: this is javascript function?

Comment: Yes, defined by every editor plugin like [tinyMCE](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/plugins/editors/tinymce/tinymce.php#L673). Using this article links, images and page breaks are inserted into articles.

Comment: Also need to mention that this worked 
jQuery(window).load(function() {
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("hello world");
    });

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.tinyMCE && window.tinyMCE.activeEditor)
      {
             tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("asdsad");
      }
    }); 
 Or
```

you can initialize tinyMCE and then setContent

```
  tinyMCE.init({
         mode : "exact",
         elements : "updateeditor",
         theme : "advanced",
         plugins : "inlinepopups, example",
         theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "example",
        });
```

Comment: The first one still does not work. The seconds one how can I initialize tinyMCE in setConent, can you give an example? 
thank you for your reply.

Comment: tinyMCE.init({  
       oninit : "tinyMCE.getInstanceById('elm1').getBody().innerHTML = 'asdsad'"

}):

Answer (score 1):

tinymce.init({
    ...
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('init', function(e) {
            console.log('init event', e);
        });
    }
});

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:event.tinymce.Editor.init